# Сортировка выборки SQL по регулярному выражению

Tags: php, sql

есть у меня в БД таблица devdata с данными предположим так выглядит

```
id IND(9) AI
name VARCHAR(255) 
...
scount VARCHAR(255)
```

суть в том что в поле scount информация помещается по определенному шаблону примерно так: 200-2000^3434^54545|120-400^3333^4444

я делаю стандартный запрос на php примерно такой

```
$tmp = mysqli_query($hdb,"SELECT * FROM idevdata ORDER BY scount REGEXP '/^[^^]*\^\K[^^]*(?=\^)/' ASC");
```

мне нужно что бы сортировка производилось по цифрам между мервыи ^ ^ (т.е. в этом примере 200-2000^3434^54545|120-400^3333^4444 будет выбираться 3434) регулярное выражение мне уже помогли найти правильно но теперь почему то такой запрос
выдает уже ошибку num_rorws - те. запрос не прошел

```
  Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

подскажите пожалуйста что я не правильно сделал в системе регулярных выражений в sql

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143565/is-there-a-way-to-order-by-regexp-in-mysql-statement и темы regexp в запросах

Comment: `ORDER BY scount+0` *цифра может быть как и однозначной так и трехзначной и более* Вы цифры и числа не перепутали?

Comment: @Akina да скорее число - а вот это scount+0 как работает можно по подробней?

Comment: *как работает можно по подробней?* Контекст выражения - числовой. Оба операнда соответственно приводятся к числовому типу. Приводя к числу строку, MySQL просто убирает нечисловой "хвост". Можно использовать более стандартное `CAST(scount AS UNSIGNED)`, но оно просто длиннее...

Comment: Разница между `+0` и `CAST` - последний не понимает научной нотации. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea74dba00852151b939b8cad8f91f278

Comment: @Akina ага то есть оно обрежет все символы начиная с первого не числового? в том числе и последующие после тире в моем случае цифры?

Comment: Ну чего спрашивать, когда можно попробовать?

Comment: @Akina да это рбаотает и так и так если конвертируете свой комент в ответ то помечу как верным)

Comment: а мысль хранить информацию в БД не "по определенному шаблону" а в **нормальном** виде не приходила в голову?

Comment: @Ипатьев ну дружище, если так данные записанны возможно так надо наверно? ны если критикуешь лучше предложи, как лучше хранить данные когда есть череда зависимостей между ними и что бы было удобно сортировать

Comment: @Ипатьев друг ты либо дай ответ по вопросу, либо уходи это не сайт-форум где люди от нечего делать срутся, к тому же я думаю это не очень профессионально рассуждать о вещах по деталям не зная всеё картины

Comment: дружище, ты попросил меня предложить лучшее решение. Я предложил.  А ты меня хаять начал. Как-то это не по-мужски.

Comment: @dantelol, перефразирую диалог - вы спросили "как правильно держать микроскоп, забивая гвозди, чтобы он не ломался". Вам посоветовали задуматься о том, чтобы использовать другой инструмент, но вы начали рассуждать о непрофессионализме... Хммм... Я бы тоже посоветовал вам задуматься об изменении формата хранения данных и почитать о концепции трех нормальных форм. Если оставить модель данных как есть, то вы постоянно будете сталкиваться проблемами, которых можно было легко избежать...

Comment: `к тому же я думаю это не очень профессионально рассуждать о вещах по деталям не зная всеё картины` - так может лучше описать вопрос детальнее, чтобы люди, которые пытаются вам помочь увидели всю картину??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что данный запрос не выполняет желаемого... Куда более правильно будет преобразовать нужные данные и уже после преобразования их сортировать...

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX(scount, '^', 2)), '^', -1) as sort FROM devdata ORDER BY sort ASC
```

**Результат выполнения:**
[image: Наглядная сортировка]